# Extract lines from multiple files based on condition in one line

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a number of directories containing text files with a pattern like this:

```
class FeatureFE():
    meta_data = MetaData(
        name='COOL_FEATURE',
        sub_type='EXTRA_COOL_FEATURES',
        required_data=[accounts, logs],
        has_graph=True,
        x_axis_label='Time',
        y_axis_label='Foo',
        graph_caption='Description of my feature',
        priority='low',
    )
```

The task I have been given is to go through each `.py` file and, if `has_graph=True`, extract the `name`, `required_data` and `graph_caption` - the end goal being a CSV structured like this:

```
name, required_data, graph_caption
'COOL_FEATURE', [accounts, logs],'Description of my feature',
```

This definitely seems doable with `awk`/`sed`/`grep`, but I'm struggling to get there. So far I've managed this:

```
grep -E -B 4 -A 5 "has_graph=True" feature_17.py | tr -s ' ' | grep '^ name\|^ required_data\|^ graph_caption' | sed 's/.*=//'
```

Which returns

```
'COOL_FEATURE',
[accounts, logs],
'Description of my feature',
```

for one file, but nothing when run on *.py.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: The desired output CSV header line `name, required_data, graph_caption` is 3 fields but the data line `'COOL_FEATURE', [accounts, logs],'Description of my feature'` is 4 fields (count the commas). You need to enclose each field in double quotes and consequently also double up any double quotes that can be present in each field (you should include that in your example) to make the output a valid CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have name=value pairs in your data I find it best to first create an array of those mappings and then simply access the values by their names. For example, with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and ENDFILE:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    numNames = split("name required_data graph_caption",names)
}

match($0,/^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*\S)\s*,\s*$/,a) {
    name  = a[1]
    value = a[2]
    name2value[name] = value
}

ENDFILE {
    if ( name2value["has_graph"] == "True" ) {
        if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
            for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
                name = names[nameNr]
                printf "%s%s", name, (nameNr<numNames ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
        for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
            name  = names[nameNr]
            value = name2value[name]
            gsub(/"/,"\"\"",value)
            printf "\"%s\"%s", value, (nameNr<numNames ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    delete name2value
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
name,required_data,graph_caption
"'COOL_FEATURE'","[accounts, logs]","'Description of my feature'"
```

I added double quotes before printing to make sure the output is a valid CSV even when your values contain `,` (as `[accounts, logs]` does) and/or double quotes.

To use the above with `find` I'd do this:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec awk -f tst.awk {} +
```

but remove this part of the script first:

```
        if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
            for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
                name = names[nameNr]
                printf "%s%s", name, (nameNr<numNames ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
```

so you don't get a header line printed once for every batch of files passed to awk from find and just add the header line manually later or print it before running the script. There's other ways to deal with that but that's the simplest.

Comment: Thanks this works really nicely. I can do it on the whole folder with `awk -f tst.awk *.py`, but is there a way to do it recursively for nested folders? (If not I can manage, you've still saved me a ton of time!)

Comment: Keep your commands that find files and commands that operate on file contents separate. The command to find files is `find` so just use it to find the files (see the `find` man page) and then call the awk script I posted on the resulting list of files.

Comment: I'm using `find . -name '*.py' | awk -f tst.awk` in the parent folder, and don't get any results. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - that's piping a list of file names to awk to read as input. You need to give awk a list of file names as arguments, not as input, so awk can open each file and read it's **contents** as input. I edited my answer to show the simplest way to use awk with find.

Comment: Many thanks! Tangentially, is there a difference between `find -exec` and `find | xargs`?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes but ask a new question tagged with those commands if you'd like information about that.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(considering that your python files will have only 1 occurrence of this class). Tested and written in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="="
  s1="\047"
  OFS=","
  print "name, required_data, graph_caption"
}
/has_graph=True/{
  found=1
}
found && /name/{
  sub(/,/,"",$2)
  name=$2
  next
}
found && /required_data/{
  sub(/,/,"",$2)
  data=$2
}
found && /graph_caption/{
  sub(/,/,"",$2)
  print s1 name s1,s1 data s1,s1 $2 s1
  nextfile
}
'  *.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'for my $key (qw( name required_data graph_caption )) {
                  ($h{$key}) = /\b$key=(.*),/;
                }
                say join ",", @h{qw{ name required_data graph_caption }};
               ' -- *.py
```

- `-n` reads the input record by record, executing the code for each one
- `-0777` reads the whole file instead of reading it line by line
- the `%h` hash is populated with values captured from a regex match, `\b` stands for a "word boundary"

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but it doesn't check for the condition, right?